# Pass a custom fixed header to auth_request in nginx

Tags: nginx, auth-request

I need some guidance to pass a static header to auth_request in nginx.
My locations config is as below:

```
location = /auth {
  internal;     
  proxy_pass http://authserver.com:8009/auth;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

And my subrequest looks like below:

```
location = /app/finance/ {
  proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
  # Custom header to be added
  proxy_set_header CallType "MAJOR";
  auth_request /auth;
  error_page 401 =401 /auth;      
  proxy_pass http://myaddservice.com:8080/finance/;
}
```

I need to pass CallType header to auth_request.I have tried with add_header, proxy_set_header but it didnt work.
I have a Rest Api to authenticate behind auth_request which is expecting the CallType header.
I cannot make it pass as a part of api header because its an internal process.

Comment: Is this `CallType` header should be passed to both `myaddservice.com:8080` and `authserver.com:8009`?

Comment: no..i simply need it in authserver.com..well it will have no impact even if passed to both..i am ok with that too...any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
location = /auth {
  internal;     
  proxy_pass http://authserver.com:8009/auth;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
  proxy_set_header CallType $calltype;
}

location = /app/finance/ {
  set $calltype "MAJOR";
  proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
  auth_request /auth;
  error_page 401 =401 /auth;      
  proxy_pass http://myaddservice.com:8080/finance/;
}
```

If the auth request will be called from some other location, the `$calltype` variable would have an empty value and the `CallType` header won't be set at all (nginx does not set the header if an empty value is passed as the parameter to `add_header` or `proxy_set_header` directives).

Comment: Is variable scope per-request?

Comment: @bobah Yes, it is. If you need to share some data with several requests, it can be a non-trivial task and I doubt it can be solved without additional third party modules. If you really need to, take a look at [this](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict).

Comment: I needed it per-request, just wanted to be sure it’s not leaking anywhere else, perfect!